# amCharts yaxis value format issue

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

Using amcharts, I am plotting a chart with 3 kinds of data. But these two creates problem.

1. Job execution duration - The value actually should be in 'hh:mm'
   format, for example 03:30 (can be read as 3 hours, 30 minutes)
2. Time of the day - The value should be in 'hh:mm' format, for example 08:30 (can be read as 8:30 am)

I tried, but i am not getting them working as expected(I want the axis values in above format). Here is my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3qe5Lg1/4/). Any suggestions/corrections would be highly appreciated!

code is under JS part : `var chart = AmCharts.makeChart`

Comment: what do you mean with "I am not getting them working"?

Comment: I have updated the problem, please check once again.

Comment: take a look here https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/

Comment: What units are your values supposed to be? Are they supposed to be hours with decimals meaning minutes? You can try creating a duration-based value axis like [this example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/duration-on-value-axis/) or just use full-fledged timestamps for your values and use a date-based value axis like [this example](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/date-based-value-axis-and-values/).

Comment: @xorspark -  Thanks for your suggestions. Now I have achieved the 1st item (duration of execution), But I am still struggling for the clock things. I will get data in string format like "10:30 AM" or "9:27 AM" only and not the complete date object with timestamps. Just wondering if I can achieve that, and the value axis should show 09:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00. I don't want to handle the timestamp in the JS part. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code

```
 return {
    'type': 'serial',
    'theme': 'light',
    'marginTop': 0,
    "autoMarginOffset": 20,
    'marginRight': 80,
    "mouseWheelZoomEnabled":true,
    "legend": {
      "align": "center",
      "listeners": [ {
        "event": "hideItem",
        "method": this.legendHandler
      }, {
        "event": "showItem",
        "method": this.legendHandler
      } ]


    },


    'dataProvider': dataProvider,
    'valueAxes': [{

      "minimum": 0,  
      "axisColor":"#FFFFFF",
      "titleColor":"#FFFFFF",
      "color":"#FFFFFF",   
        "strictMinMax": true,
      'axisAlpha': 0,
      'position': 'left',
     // "title":selectedParameter +" Level  ("+type+")"
    },
    {
      "logarithmic": true,
      "dashLength": 1,
      position: "left",

    }
  ],
    'graphs': graphlinelist,

    'chartScrollbar': {
      'graph': 'g1',
      'gridAlpha': 0,
      'color': '#888888',
      'scrollbarHeight': 55,
      'backgroundAlpha': 0,
      'selectedBackgroundAlpha': 0.1,
      'selectedBackgroundColor': '#888888',
      'graphFillAlpha': 0,
      'autoGridCount': true,
      'selectedGraphFillAlpha': 0,
      'graphLineAlpha': 0.2,
      'graphLineColor': '#c2c2c2',
      'selectedGraphLineColor': '#888888',
      'selectedGraphLineAlpha': 1
    },
    'chartCursor': {
      'categoryBalloonDateFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS',
      'cursorAlpha': 0,
      'valueLineEnabled': true,
      'valueLineBalloonEnabled': true,
      'valueLineAlpha': 0.5,
      'fullWidth': true
    },
    'dataDateFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS',
    'categoryField': 'Date',
    'categoryAxis': {
      'minPeriod': 'ss',
      "labelColorField":"#FFFFFF",
      'parseDates': true,
      "axisColor":"#FFFFFF",
      "titleColor":"#FFFFFF",
      "color":"#FFFFFF",
      'minorGridAlpha': 0.1,
      "title": "Time(24 hours)",
      'minorGridEnabled': true
    },
    'export': {
      'enabled': true
    }
  };
}
```

You can either use 'dataDateFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS',
  or 
'dataDateFormat': 'NN:SS',